# Calculate the X,Y values of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I guess am confused somewhere. I have the length(l) and breadth(b) of an ellipse enclosing rectangle. I know the center point and the angle(x) that the line makes with the center. I want to know the coordinates of the point at which it meets the ellipse. Is it possible? If so how do I do it?

Comment: You mean ellipse, I guess.

Comment: @user37238 yup. sorry for the typo. corrected.

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/280937/86986) should provide some clues.

Comment: You mention you know the angle some line makes with the center. What line are you talking about here? The rectangle's diagonal, maybe?

Comment: @DavidH any arbitary line that originates from center of ellipse and passes through the ellipse at a given angle x. I need to know the point at which it meets the ellipse.

Comment: See answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475436/2d-point-projection-on-an-ellipse/475505#475505

Answer (score 0):

The above link in the comment form @bubba is the answer...

[image: Formulae to calculate the points. The image has the required formulaes..]